# Postgres: relation does not exist error when table exists on public schema

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have a table that was dumped to Postgres using Pandas and Pandas can read it just fine using the `read_sql_table` command but I can't seem to be able to access it using SQL. When I run the `\dt` command, I get the table listed under the public schema as one of the existing tables.

```
                 List of relations
 Schema |                Name                | Type  |  Owner   
--------+------------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | "e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036" | table | postgres
```

But when I run `SELECT * FROM "e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036";` I get the relation does not exist error. I have tried the following:

- `SELECT * FROM "e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036"`
- `SELECT * FROM "public"."e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036"`
- Granted usage to public schema to the user by doing `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO postgres;`
- Checked this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354756/postgres-database-error-relation-does-not-exist) that suggest it might be the identifier length is too long but my identifier length is 32 bytes with Postgres allowing up to 63 bytes by default

When I run `SHOW search_path;` it shows `"$user", public` which is what it should be but for some reason Postgres keeps saying the relation does not exist.

Other helpful information:

- I'm running Postgres in a docker container from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

Any idea on what might be causing the error here?

Comment: Are you logged in as the table owner `postgres`? (btw: it's not a good idea to create tables using the superuser or use the superuser account for your application)

Comment: Yes I'm logged in as the `postgres` user. Thanks for the hint, I'm only doing this on my dev machine and on production I'm using a different user

Comment: May I know why tag pandas here ?

Comment: The table was created with pandas' `to_sql` method and pandas could read it just fine using the `read_sql` method so I thought it might have something to do with it. I'll remove the tag now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table name contains double quotes.

Embedding double quotes in an identifier follows the same rules as embedding single quotes in a string literal: you need to double them:

So the table was created with something like this:

```
create table """e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036"""(...);
```

You need to use the same syntax when you select from it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM """e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036""";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I suspected that at first but tried doing `SELECT * 
FROM "\"e7b6a2e19789418e9e48fd34e981b036\""` which kept throwing syntax errors